# chisq.test() on transition matrix for point-of-gaze

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, transition, chi-squared

All,

I am trying to do a chisq.test() for eye data in a transition matrix where each row represents the tally of gaze from one area of 7 areas of interest (AoIs) to each of the others. In this analysis, it makes no sense for there to be a transition from one AoI to itself. Hence, those fields contain NAs.

I have tried a variety of different formats from a basic tabular input of 8 columns and rows (with the top row being the headers and the left column being the "from's"), to a simple three column data from (from, to, values).

My data.frame looks like this:

```
from <- c("frLS", "frLF", "frRF", "frRS", "frIns", "frEng", "frOthr")
frLS <- c(NA, 77,3, 0, 17, 0, 1)
frLF <- c(18, NA, 14, 1, 56, 2, 9)
frRF <- c(1, 52, NA, 15, 16, 1, 14)
frRS <- c(0, 7, 35, NA, 13, 15, 30)
frIns <- c(3, 54, 2, 1, NA, 4, 37)
frEng <- c(0, 9, 0, 3, 27, NA, 61)
frOthr <- c(2, 60, 2, 5, 27, 4, NA)

aoi.df <- data.frame(from, frLS, frLF, frRF, frRS, frIns, frEng, frOthr)
```

(Note that this is not actual data, but example data taken from Holmqvist's et al., textbook on Eye Tracking.)

Note I have also tried this as a matrix

```
aoi.matrix <- matrix(c(frLS, frLF, frRF, frRS, frIns, frEng, frOthr), ncol=7)
```

But I believe the problem is the NAs not the form of the data but, if that is the case, I am not sure how to handle it.

Comment: Have you tried looking into Markov chains (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Stationary_distribution_relation_to_eigenvectors_and_simplexes)? They may not do the anlalysis you're looking for, but they could give you some insight. You can pretty easily predict the stationary distribution. In other words, you can predict how many people will be staring at each object after you let them sit there for a really long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is how to handle a chisq.test with NAs. One thing I did not know when I asked this question is that the NAs in my matrix are what are called "structural zeros." Hence, they are not zeros as "zero" is a count nor are they some unexplained blip in data collection. Rather, they arise from the structure of the data set. In the case of the transition matrix, we do not allow a transition from object "A" to itself, only to other objects.

All of that said, it turns out that there is (of course) an R package for that!! I need to refer you to the aylmer documentation for a more detailed explanation, but I pretty much got what I was hoping that the chi.square would give me from:

aylmer.test(aoi.df, alternative = "two.sided", simulate.p.value = TRUE)

Note that I did have to remove the first column of "from" names, but other than that things worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `NA`s indeed is the problem. The error message is quite clear:

```
> chisq.test(aoi.matrix)
Error in chisq.test(aoi.matrix) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite
```

Either you need to substitute the `NA` with something else, say, `0` if that makes sense.

Now, I don't quite understand your problem. But are you sure that a `chisq.test` is what you want to do? It doesn't make any sense to me. Recall that you're testing for independence. However, if the diagonal elements always are zero or `NA`, then they cannot be independent.

Comment: I agree that you might want to consider something other than the chi square test. Also note that the assumptions of the chi square test aren't valid if there are cells with expected values of zero (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Assumptions). In your case, all of the cells on the diagonal are expected to be zero.